# Find $T$, $N$, and $k$ for vector

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

$$    x(t) = ( t , \sin(4t), \cos(4t) )$$

I am unsure on what they are referring to here. would $T$ be the tangent and therefore:

$$    x'(t) = ( 1 , 4\cos(4t) , 4\sin(4t) ) ?$$

Thanks :)

Also, the tangential and normal concepts of acceleration?

Comment: Psst...the derivative of cosine is...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find some components of the [Frenet-Serret Frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas), as well as the curvature. Understanding that frame should make the concepts of tangential and normal acceleration easier to understand - it's much easier to visualize.

$T$ = Tangent vector

$N$ = Normal vector

$k$ = curvature

$X'(t) = s'(t)T(t)$ where $s$ is the speed (ie $||X'(t)||$) and $T$ is the unit tangent vector

$T(t) = \dfrac{X'(t)}{||X'(t)||} $

$N(t) = \dfrac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$

$k(t) = \dfrac{||T'(t)||}{s'(t)}$

The **T** angent vector gives the direction in which the curve is moving. It's the derivative. The **N** ormal vector gives the direction in which the tangent vector is changing. It's perpendicular to the tangent vector. The curvature **k** is, loosely, the amount the curve is curving at a given point. The higher the curvatuve, the tighter the curve. A circle has constant curvature (which happens to be $1/r$).

Comment: Are the Tangent and the Velocity essentially the same thing? I was just using the derivative of x(t) for the tangent vector, and the same for velocity. But you say the tangent is Velocity / Abs(Velocity)?

Comment: The tangent $T$ is the direction, so it's given as a unit vector (vector / norm of vector = unit vector giving direction).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The acceleration is $x''$ which you should be able to calculate-just one more step of the same.  Then to get the tangential and normal components of the acceleration, you need to resolve the acceleration into the part parallel to $x'$ and the part perpendicular to $x'$.  If the angle between $x'$ and $x''$ is $\theta$, the tangential component of $x''$ is $|x''| \cos \theta \hat{x'}=\frac {x'' \cdot x'}{x' \cdot x'}x'$ and the normal is what is left.